# BitmapFactory.decodeResource is not working API > 19

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I'm trying to get an image from the folder /drawable but I receive null when api > 19. Does anyone know what the problem is?

All images I use are vectors.

```
dog.setImagen(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dog));
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem with this code.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(Drawable vectorDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dog)).getBitmap();
dog.setImagen(bm);
```

Comment: it doesn't work, throw an Exception "android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable"

Comment: Well then don't cast it to bitmap drawable. However you can draw any drawable onto a canvas (in your case one assigned to a bitmap). See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)